# github hello world coming up with error

Tags: macos, git, github

```
test afrieden$ mkdir hello-world
test afrieden$ cd hello-world/
hello-world afrieden$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/afrieden/test/hello-world/.git/
hello-world afrieden$ touch README
hello-world afrieden$ git add README
hello-world afrieden$ git commit -m "first message"
[master (root-commit) 881750d] first message
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 README
hello-world afrieden$ git remote add origin git@github.com:alexfrieden/hello-world.git
hello-world afrieden$ git push origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Why am I getting this error?  I set up my ssh correctly.

Comment: There are a few solutions to this error, see https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found

Comment: perhaps you wanted to name it alexfrieden-hello-world instead of hello-world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you need to create the repo on the GitHub side first.

Right now, https://github.com/alexfrieden/hello-world returns 404.